# Eclipse RCP + Jetty 9.4.8 + Websocket

Tags: eclipse, websocket, jetty, rcp, equinox

I'm writing an Eclipse RCP application. I use the embedded Jetty server to handle Rest Services. It works fine.
Now I want to add a WebSocket Connection. I didn't find any Jetty Websocket bundle in the Eclipse repository. So I've created my own plugin with the differents Jetty WebSocket jars.
I've created a WebSocketServlet and a wetsocket client to test it.
When I try to initiate de Websocket, I get the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find required ServletContext attribute: org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.doStart(WebSocketServerFactory.java:311)
```

Does someone have a solution ?

Thanks.

Cedric.

Comment: Jetty 9.4.8 is old, and is also [subject to several security bulletins](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html).  I would suggest upgrading to 9.4.30.v2020611

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix versions of Jetty jars, make sure you are using the same version for all Jetty jars.

Bundles for Jetty can be found at [the listed location](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/download.html).

https://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.
The Jetty version bundled with my Eclipse version is the 9.4.8. I known, I have to migrate to a newer version but I didn't do it yet (and I get some troubles with Java 9+ and the Jersey layer embedded in eclipse (the rsconnector).

The ServletContextLauncher present into the Jetty eclipse bundle set up correctly the DecoratedObjectFactory but It doesn't seem to be used to initialise the websocket server layer.
I've already did some tests a few years ago with an oldest Jetty release (also bundled in an eclipse plugin) and I was able to open a websocket without error. But, not with the 9.4.8 one...